# One to many relationship not working in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-many, entity-framework-migrations

In my MVC project I'm using EF Code First. 
I have 2 tables.
Table1:

```
namespace CL_AHR_CRM.Models
{
    public partial class Leads
    {
        [Key]
        public int LeadID { get; set; }  
        [NotMapped]            
        public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int NamePrefixID { get; set; }

        public virtual NamePrefixes NamePrefixes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Table2:

```
namespace CL_AHR_CRM.Models
{
    public partial class NamePrefixes
    {
        [Key]
        public int NamePrefixID { get; set; }
        public string Prefix { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Leads> Leads { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now I want them to have a one to many relationship. But it is not working.
Where is the problem?
I'm using migration mode in ef.

Comment: In constructor `NamePrefixes()` try to  add:
 `Leads= new HashSet<Leads>();`

Comment: Explain what is "not working".

Comment: "Not working" means that there is no relationship between the 2 tables. When I check the database in SQL there is no foreign key. When creating diagram there is no relationship.

Comment: I think the reason why ef don't autocreate your realationships is the use of unconventional id names. Ef will look for something like ClassName + Id, e.g. NamePrefixesId. Using only Id for primary keys and ClassName+Id for foreign keys will probably do the trick. For more info, read through this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx Alternatively use fluent mappings as suggested below

Comment: I will definitely try that. But I do not think it is going to work because there are other classes like "Addresses" with pk "AddressID" which is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try map the relationship with Fluent API?

In your DbContext class, you should override the OnModelCreating method and generate the relationship like this:

```
public class MyEntities : DbContext
{
     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Leads>().HasRequired(m => m.NamePrefixes).WithMany(m => m.Leads).HasForeignKey(m => m.NamePrefixID);
     }
}
```

This code block may solve your problem.

**UPDATE**:

I think you should use data annotations in the virtual property to make it work.

In Lead class:

```
[ForeignKey("NamePrefixID")]
public virtual NamePrefixes NamePrefixes { get; set; }
```

Can you try it?

Regards

Comment: I will try this and let you know. But I want to know why this one does not do the job. I mean it should. Right?

Comment: No it did not work. I change the whole structure. Thank you anyway.